# How do I let Sympy parse an expression while only regarding arbitrary previously defined strings as symbols?

Tags: python, parsing, sympy

So what I am trying to do is write a script that lets me input some function and a list of the variables inside it, then processes it into some other formular, computes a result, and then outputs both the new formular and the result as Latex code. Everything works fine as long as I only input variables which do not contain "^", "{", or "}". The problem is, I want to use, or, at the very least, output the names exactly as they are written in my Latex document, and as such they do often contain these characters.

I am aware that there is a built-in Latex-Parser in Sympy, but as I understood it requires some other package (antlr4), and I would like to try to avoid that, since I am planning to distribute the script to my fellow students, and don't want to add another requirement for running the script.

So what I thought of is that I could use the list of variable names (which I input anyway together with their values to allow the program to compute a final result): I tried to define a "transformation", as it is described on the Sympy documentation on parsing. It looks like this:

```
#Defining the transformation
    def can_split(symbol):
#Check if symbol is in one of the lists of inputted values (the two lists contain tuples of variable names[0] and their corresponding values[1])
        if symbol not in ([i[0] for i in uncertainValues]+[i[0] for i in certainValues]):
             return _token_splittable(symbol)
        return False
    
#Read function definition from TKinter text field, split only by custom defined symbols
    function=parse_expr(functionEntry.get("1.0", "end-1c"),transformations = (split_symbols_custom(can_split)))
```

The problem is that if I run this script, and input e. g. "a^b*c", and the variable names "a^b" and "c", which should normally be read as "the variable 'a^b' multiplied with the variable 'c'"I get the exception: "NameError: name 'a' is not defined".

If anyone could help me with this, or maybe propose another way to do this properly, I would be very thankful. Also, if there is more code or context needed to find a better solution, I'll provide more - I just felt everything would get too long-winding if I explained the whole idea. But as I said, I'll be glad to do that if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Quick but dirty workaround:

For now I ended up using the dirty method of replacing all problematic characters with unique strings at input, and replacing them with their symbols again before outputting.